# Android Emulator React Native Geolocation not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, react-redux

I am working on the geolocation code, on android studio using windows. But for some reason my present location is not being picked. I tried  to use  other options like enableHighAccuracy:false. also tried to run Telnet, and apply geo fix long lat, but nothing happens.

Please see relevant code that actually works when i tested on expo snacks.

```
  findCurrentLocationAsync=()=>{

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position) => {
         //   console.log(position);
            let lat=position.coords.latitude;
            let long=position.coords.longitude;
            
            this.setState({
              markerPosition: {
                lat: lat,
                lng: long
            },
            mapPosition: {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: long,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }
            });

             Geocoder.from( this.state.mapPosition.latitude , this.state.mapPosition.longitude ).then(
              response => {
                  const address = response.results[0].formatted_address,
                        addressArray =  response.results[0].address_components,
                        city = this.getCity( addressArray ),
                        area = this.getArea( addressArray ),
                        state = this.getState( addressArray );
                        zip = this.getZip( addressArray );
      
                console.log(addressArray)
      
                  this.setState( {
                      address: ( address ) ? address : '',
                      area: ( area ) ? area : '',
                      city: ( city ) ? city : '',
                      state: ( state ) ? state : '',
                      zip: ( zip ) ? zip : '',
                  } )
              },
              error => {
              //  console.error( error );
              }
          )

          },
         
         //{ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 },
         ///()=>console.log(lat)  
      );

    
     };
```

I would appreciate suggestions

thanks
sal

Comment: Also post concerning code.

Comment: please check. the code works. but not picking the current location. just pasted the relevant code. thanks

Comment: you have used expo-location. but i think its more of andorid problem. do you see probelm using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Emulaltor location settings]

If you didnt, set location using android emu settings. Android emulator has settings bar on right. Click "three point" button and mark the location you want to emulated then set location.

If you completed these steps, ignore it.

Comment: can anyone explain why we are not getting lat long in this expo snack code. i could relate this code to my problem thanks https://snack.expo.io/@coder79/geolocation-example